# Delphi CheckListBox and MainMenu

Tags: delphi

I have some problem with iteration in delphi. First, I have 2 MenuItems. Menu 1 has 5 submenus, and Menu 2 has 3 submenus. The idea is, if I checked checkListbox, which has 8 items (submenu of Menu 1 and Menu 2), it will checked submenu of Menu 1 and Menu 2.

```
[MainMenu 1] = menu1, menu2, menu3, menu4, menu5; (submenu)
[MainMenu 2] = menu1, menu2, menu3; (submenu)

CheckListBox = menu1, menu2, menu3, menu4, menu5 (MainMenu item 1), menu6, menu7, menu8(MainMenu item 2);
```

I tried with some code like:

```
for x := 0 to checkListBox.Items.Count - 1 do

begin

  if checkListBox.Checked[x] then

begin

Menu1.items[x].Checked := true;
end;
    end;
```

This code run failed, because list bounds of MainMenu 1 is 1 to 5.

if I try this,

```
MainMenu.items[0][2].Checked:= true;
```

sure it can be spesific, but not as I think.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something along these lines:

```
var
  CheckIndex, MenuIndex: Integer;
  Checked: Boolean;
  Menu: TMenu;
....
for CheckIndex := 0 to checkListBox.Items.Count - 1 do begin
  Checked := checkListBox.Checked[CheckIndex];
  if CheckIndex < Menu1.Items.Count then begin
    Menu := Menu1;
    MenuIndex := CheckIndex;
  end else begin
    Menu := Menu2;
    MenuIndex := CheckIndex - Menu1.Items.Count;
  end;
  Menu.Items[MenuIndex].Checked := Checked;
end;
```

I'm not sure I fully understand your question. I certainly can't see where the sub-menus come into it. However, I hope that the ideas expressed above are useful.

Comment: unfortunately I can't attach image. But your code give me idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider using ActionList and actions?

You do know that you can "bind" each menu item to its own action and that while doing so menu items properties like Checked and Enabled directly reflect the Checked and Enabled properties of the Action that has been "binded" to that specific menu item.

Using Action list you are accesing specific actions by their index (which I belive what you are trying to do) and since the changes made to Actions are relfected in Menu items binded to that specific action you don't need to edit each specific meni item individually and therefore don't have to worry about menu structure.

Infact you can bind multiple menu items from multiple menues to one action and changing the Checked or Enabled property of this action will affect all the menu items that have been binded to this specific action.
This comes especially usefull if you are using combination of MainMenu (with or without submenues) and PopupMenu (again with or woithout submenues).

Comment: Nice answer. To be honest, I haven't think up over there. It will help me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: I found actionlist difficult for hide and show. ActionList work with actions inside, if I try with ActionList.action[x].visible := true or actionList.action.index[x].visible := true it gonna wrong at all.